# Conan: Command Not Found

Tags: shell-script, python, path, command

I'm using a RPI 3B

`uname -a` returns: `4.14.98-v7+ #1200 armv71`

OS is `stretch`

`gcc version is 4.9.3`

I'm attempting to setup my RPi to be a BLE gateway as per [this project](https://www.hackster.io/wolkabout-writer/bluetooth-iot-gateway-b61a1d#comments) on hackster.io. I executed the first few commands:

`git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/Wolkabout/WolkGateway.git`

`sudo apt-get install mosquitto cmake python python-pip && python -m pip install conan`

The Bash Script

then I ran a bash script (configure.sh) that contains the following:

```
!/usr/bin/env bash

cp tools/git/pre-commit .git/hooks/pre-commit
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit

pushd out
conan install -s compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 --build=missing ..
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
popd
```

The Output of the Bash Script

the terminal outputs:

```
line 21: conan: command not found
```

line 21 is the line with `conan`.

Then I get a CMake error:

```
CMakeLists.txt:(20) (include):
include could not find load file:
/home/pi/Wolk...conanbuildinfo.cmake
```

Maybe Conan Isn't in My `PATH`

My thought was that the command `conan` isn't in my `$PATH` so I checked `PIP`:

```
pip show conan
```

this gave me the location of `conan`:

```
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I then added that path to my `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This didn't work, causing the same error when re-running the aforementioned bash script (configure.sh)

Installing Conan From Source

I went [here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html) and installed `conan` from source:

```
 git clone https://github.com/conan-io/conan.git
 cd conan
 pip install -r conans/requirements.txt
```

The Python Script to Add Conan to my `PATH`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

conan_repo_path = "/home/pi/conan"
```

ABSOLUTE PATH TO CONAN 
    REPOSITORY FOLDER

```
sys.path.append(conan_repo_path)
from conans.client.command import main
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

This worked. It showed me the `conan commands help` output.

What is this python script doing differently then when I execute configure.sh (bash script)?

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro did you down vote my question, if so, please provide the reason so I   know for next time.

Comment: You're referring to two different paths in your shell script and your Python script. If you do `export PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/conan`, does the shell script work then?

Comment: @Haxiel -  Thanks for the help but the output of the bash script still say conan:command not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing conan:

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto cmake python python-pip && python -m pip install conan
```

the later half:

```
python -m pip install conan
```

should be installed using sudo:

```
sudo python -m pip install conan
```

If this doesn't work, try uninstalling conan:

```
pip uninstall conan
```

and then reinstall:

```
sudo pip install conan
```

Currently my RPi is running the configure.sh script successfully.

Answer (score 7):

On ubuntu 18.04, after installation of the software performing 
`pip3 install --user conan`
or 
`pip install --user conan`

Doesn't properly link the binary into your path. You could set the path usually because --user installs it into `~/.local/` (on a per user basis) because installing with sudo globally breaks things.

One quick option is to merely create the symlink by performing 
`sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/conan /usr/bin/conan`

it's a small work around, however you could also add `~/.local/bin` as such: 
`export PATH=$PATH:/home/<user>/.local/bin`

and you will also be able to execute any installed binaries from here as well.

Comment: I don't see why my answer wasn't the accepted answer, while it has 3 upvotes, and the accepted answer has 0 upvotes.